# Canvas render sometimes and doesn't render other times

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

It is not completely random, at some point in my code I create a matrix, the smaller the matrix, the higher the chances of the canvas rendering normally. Even if I completely remove the matrix it sometimes won't render and show me a white screen.

Here is the code in case anyone wants to try:

## Game Frame

```java
package com.GameLearning.main;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    private static GameEngine gameEngine;

    public GameFrame () {
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true); 
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        
        gameEngine = new GameEngine(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        this.add(gameEngine);
        gameEngine.start();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        frame = new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

## Game Engine

```java
package com.GameLearning.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class GameEngine extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    // Loop tools
    private Thread thread;
    private Boolean isRunning;
    // Game attributes
    private final int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    // Game elements
    private Background background;

    public GameEngine (int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
        this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;

        background = new Background(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void tick() {
        background.tick();
    }

    private void render() {
        // Get buffer strategy
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        // Init layer
        BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = layer.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        // Render game
        background.render(g);
        // Draw Graphics
        g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        // show
        bs.show();
    }

    public synchronized void start () {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        isRunning = true;
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        // Tools for the main loop
        double desiredFPS = 60;
        double nanoInterval = 1e9 / desiredFPS;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long delta;
        // Main loop
        while (isRunning) {
            delta = System.nanoTime() - lastTime;
            if (delta >= nanoInterval) {
                lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                // tick and render
                tick();
                render();
            }
        }        
    }

}
```

## Background

```java
package com.GameLearning.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Background {
    private static final int cellSize = 10;
    private int x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    private String[][] matrix;

    public Background (int x, int y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
        this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
         
        matrix = new String[WIDTH / cellSize][HEIGHT / cellSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = "0";
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick () {

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        // render back background
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        // render background
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                g.drawString(matrix[i][j], i * cellSize, j * cellSize + cellSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The background is where I create the matrix, increasing the cellSize reduces the size of the matrix, increasing the chances of the canvas render (but not providing me the results I want)

Comment: I would by having a look at the [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), it has a really good example of how you should be using it

Comment: This `this.pack();` followed by `gameEngine = new GameEngine(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());` and `this.add(gameEngine);` is problematic, packing an empty window is basically going to make it assume it's smallest size, so you're probably going to get weird results from the `getWidth/Height` calls, probably with one been zero, so, nothing will ever get painted because of it

Comment: I'd also be worried about `matrix = new String[WIDTH / cellSize][HEIGHT / cellSize];`, which may result in array of `0` length

Comment: Get rid of `synchronized` on the `start` and `run` methods, this causing no end of issues

Comment: Rather then doing `BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage` each time `render` is called, I would create a instance once (or every time the window size has changed), otherwise you're creating a lot of short lived objects which will add a GC overhead which will degrade the performance.  I would also pass the renderable area to `Background` and, again, resize the contents if it changes, otherwise re-use the previous cached values.  Your "main loop" is also free wheeling, which is going to degrade performance.  You will need to add in some kind of `Thread.sleep` call at some point

Comment: You are doing quite a few things wrong.  First, don't extend `JFrame`; just use an instance.  Don't use `Canvas`, use `JPanel`.  And painting should be done in the overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of `JPanel`  check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) section on painting.  You should also check out the Swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) class.

Comment: @WJS - There's nothing "wrong" with using `Canvas` in this way, assuming you want to make use of the low level APIs and control the rendering process (ie make your own "main loop"), but that's contextual to the desired results ‍♂️

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, everything I have read says it is antiquated, And I have never needed it when doing graphics.  But I will yield to the expert. BTW, the API says the paint method must be overridden when doing custom graphics.  Yet I see no `paint` method.

Comment: @WJS `BufferStrategy` gives you direct access to control over the paint pipeline, rather then relying on Swing's paint pipeline.  So, in this case, you become responsible for scheduling the paint passes, hence the "main loop" thread and `render` methods.  You're also not tied to the Event Dispatching Thread, which is another added complication, but what it does is it gives you access to the "lowest level" possible access to the rendering pipeline Java provides (closest to the metal), so it's generally used for "high performance" output - so again, it comes down to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @WJS I, personally, would start with a `JPanel` and Swing `Timer`, if that wasn't giving me the performance I needed, then I'd consider a `BufferStrategy`

Comment: @MadProgrammer.  Interesting.  Did not know that about Canvas.  Thanks for the education.

Comment: But still, but still, it's pure *AWT*, technology from 1995 that was superseded Swing a few years later, and then superseded yet again by JavaFX in 2018.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, you could just make use of the OpenGL bindings for Java ... if you really want some pain  - and all the trouble I've had getting JavaFX just to work  (oh, and interestingly, Swing came first (or at least the core idea/concepts), but Netscape insisted that the API make use of native components, so they wrote AWT/released before it)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I haven't seen that mentioned in quite a while. To be honest, I've been spending more of my time in JSS/CSS/HTML land, and all the myriad libraries and frameworks there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh wow, you really like pain 

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
public GameFrame () {
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true); 
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    
    gameEngine = new GameEngine(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    this.add(gameEngine);
    gameEngine.start();
}
```

is problematic on a number of levels.

First, you maximize the window, then you call `pack` which will cause the window to "pack" itself around the preferred size of it's content, you've not added anything to the window yet, so it's likely to size to `0x0` (because you've removed the window decorations).  So when you call `getWidth`/`getHeight`, you're likely getting one or both to return `0`.

For me...

```
public synchronized void start () {
    //...
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    //...
}
```

`synchronized` was causing no end of issues, basically locked up the entire window.  I can't see how `run` needs to be `synchronized` anyway, doesn't really make sense to me.

While on the subject, your "main loop" is free wheeling, this is a bad idea as it will consume all your CPU cycles and prevent anything else from getting done (thread starvation).  You should put a small `Thread.sleep` call in to allow other threads to be scheduled to run.

This...

```
private void render() {
    // Get buffer strategy
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    // Init layer
    BufferedImage layer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = layer.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // Render game
    background.render(g);
    // Draw Graphics
    g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    // show
    bs.show();
}
```

is unoptimised.  You're creating a short lived `BufferedImage`, this is going to place strain on the garbage collection process and will have a degrading impact on your programs performance.  You're also creating two `Graphics` contexts but are never disposing of them.

Instead, I would create a instance field and initialise the `BufferedImage` when it's need (ie is `nil` or the size of the window changes)

You should also have a read of the [BufferStrategy JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it has an excellent example of how you should be using `BufferStrategy`.

I don't think there is any need to pass the `width` and `height` to the `Background` via it's constructor, you'd be better passing it to the `render` method, this way you have a better chance of responding to window size changes.

`BufferStrategy` is a low level API and unless you absolutely must have control of the rendering pipeline and need to be as close to "metal" as you can get in Java, I would consider, instead, staring with a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method and then using a Swing `Timer` as the main rendering loop.

If that's not giving your the performance level you desire, then I'd consider
using a `BufferStrategy`

## Possible runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GameEngine engine = new GameEngine(100, 100);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(engine);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                engine.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class GameEngine extends Canvas implements Runnable {
        // Loop tools
        private Thread thread;
        private Boolean isRunning;
        // Game attributes
        private final int targetWidth, targetHeight;
        // Game elements
        private Background background;

        public GameEngine(int width, int height) {
            this.targetWidth = width;
            this.targetHeight = height;
            background = new Background();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        }

        private void tick() {
            background.tick();
        }

        private BufferedImage layer;

        private void render() {
            // Get buffer strategy
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            if (bs == null) {
                this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }

            if (layer == null || layer.getWidth() != getWidth() || layer.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
                layer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            }
            Graphics layerGraphics = layer.createGraphics();
            background.render(layerGraphics, getWidth(), getHeight());
            layerGraphics.dispose();
            do {
                // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                do {
                    // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                    // to make sure the strategy is validated
                    Graphics graphics = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                    // Render to graphics
                    graphics.drawImage(layer, 0, 0, this);
                    // Dispose the graphics
                    graphics.dispose();

                    // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                    // were restored
                } while (bs.contentsRestored());

                // Display the buffer
                bs.show();

                // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
            } while (bs.contentsLost());
        }

        public void start() {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            isRunning = true;
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Tools for the main loop
            double desiredFPS = 60;
            double nanoInterval = 1e9 / desiredFPS;
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            long delta;
            // Main loop
            while (isRunning) {
                delta = System.nanoTime() - lastTime;
                if (delta >= nanoInterval) {
                    lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                    // tick and render
                    tick();
                    render();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Background {
        private static final int cellSize = 10;
        private String[][] matrix;

        public Background() {
        }

        public void tick() {

        }

        public void render(Graphics g, int width, int height) {
            // render back background
            if (matrix == null || matrix.length == 0 || matrix.length != width || matrix[0].length != height) {
                matrix = new String[width / cellSize][height / cellSize];
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                        matrix[i][j] = "0";
                    }
                }
            }

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            // render background
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                    g.drawString(matrix[i][j], i * cellSize, j * cellSize + cellSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help out, here are some points:
 - In the GameFrame the pack was unnecessary but unharmful in anyway, it makes sure the frame is packed in the maximum dimensions of the monitor. To make sure, I printed the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` before instantiating the game and it never returned 0, even when the game didn't render;
 - Agree synchronized is not necessary, I was using some old code I had as a base and didn't pay enough attention to this part;
 - Thread starvation noted and fixed;
 - to be continued...

Comment: - I don't want the matrix to be calculated every loop, right now I'm using zeros as a placeholder, but it is going to be random at first and then slowly changing;
 - Finally, agreed, I should have a better look at the BufferStrategy documentation, I fill like my mistake might be lying there.

This is just the first step of the project, and I will need to control the loop in the future.

Please let me know if you figure why it is randomly not working. I'll bring news in case I find anything.

Comment: I didn’t say to recalculate each loop - but recalculate if the size changes

Comment: *” pack was unnecessary but unharmful in anyway, it makes sure the frame is packed in the maximum dimensions of the monitor”* isn’t actually how it works